# Getting error while adding "node.name" as a variable for elastic search in azure container instances

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I am deploying elasticsearch container instance but when I am adding the environment variable "node.name" I am getting the below error

```
The environment variable name in container 'dev-elasticsearch' of container group 'devt-elasticsearch' is invalid. A valid environment variable name must start with alphabetic character or '_', followed by a string of alphanumeric characters or '_' (e.g. 'my_name',  or 'MY_NAME',  or 'MyName').
```

here is the snippet of yml file

```
api-version: 2018-10-01
location: japaneast
name: dev-elasticsearch
properties:
  containers:
    - name: dev-elasticsearch
      properties:
        environmentVariables:
          - name: 'node.name'
            value: es-dev
          - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
            value: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
```

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Run into the same error, I've created an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/issues/19173

Answer (score 0):

Try without quotes for the value,

```
 - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
   value: -Xms512m -Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error shows, your variable name `node.name` is invalid. It doesn't match the naming rules of the Azure Container group. You can change the variable name like this:

```
properties:
  environmentVariables:
    - name: node_name
      value: es-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

As another workaround you could build a custom Docker image as such:

```
FROM elasticsearch:7.8.1

ENV name=node.name
```

You'll then have to host it with ACR, Dockerhub or similar